Getting Data from a Jacksonised Object duing unit test
I'm trying to mock out RestServer calls, but It's not generating parseable JSON:
A Simple Class like so:
@SuperBuilder
@Data
@Setter
@Jacksonized
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
Public Class Blurb {
   String field1;
   String field2;
   String field3;
}

Used in a unit test like so:
Blurb blurb = blurb.builder().build();
System.out.println(blurb);



restServiceServerMock
 .expect(manyTimes(), request to("some-url")
 .andExpect(header(set a header))
 .andExpect(method(HTTPMethod.POST))
 .andExpect(content.json("{'field':'value'}"))
 .andRespond(withSuccess("%s".formatted(blurb), MediaType.APPLICATION.JSON

somemethodwhichticklestherestservice

but running the unit test it falls over with:
JSONParseException Unrecognised token 'Blurb' was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false'
I was expecting that my built blurb of type Blurb would contain nicely formatted JSON like:
{
  "field1" : null,
  "field2" : null,
  "field3" : null
}

but instead it seems to prepend the class to the values, as
System.out.println(blurb)

gives:
Blurb(field1=null,field2=null,field3=null)

How can I make sure that my blurb object is parseable JSON? I thought that was the whole point of this sort of application.  Please note I'm making the assumption that null values should be fine.

toString doesn't create json it creates whatever you decided (or lombok in this case) decided to put in. If you want JSON you will need to pass it through Jackson to get JSON.

where am I using toString ?

System.out.println(blurb); and withSuccess("%s".formatted(blurb) that automatically calls toString and you are probably also doing something similar in somemethodwhichticklestherestservice but you excluded that information.

There was all sorts of things wrong with this, in addition to the comments.  I ended up doing this and it worked OK:
restServiceServerMock
 .expect(manyTimes(), request to("some-url")
 .andExpect(header(set a header))
 .andExpect(method(HTTPMethod.POST))
 .andExpect(content.json("{'field':'value'}"))
 .andRespond(withSuccess("""
 {
     "field1" : null,
     "field2" : null,
     "field3" : null
 }""", Media_Type.APPLICATION_JSON));

